# Torch installation error with the shell profile

Tags: shell, terminal, bash, torch

I am using mac osx el capitan. 
I did the first two parts without errors:

```
git clone https://github.com/torch/distro.git ~/torch --recursive
cd ~/torch; bash install-deps;
```

When I do the third part , `./install.sh` I get the following error:

There are two parts of the error I believe. One is regarding using iPython and second has something to do with the `.profile`. Please help me out here.

```
cp -r ~/.ipython/profile_torch ~/.ipython/profile_itorch
cmake -E make_directory build && cd build && cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/Users/PJ/torch/install/bin/.." -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/Users/PJ/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/itorch/scm-1" && make   
else
  echo "Error: could not find ipython in PATH. Do you have it installed?"
fi


rm: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/ipython_config.py: Permission denied
rm: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/ipython_kernel_config.py: Permission denied
rm: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/log: Permission denied
rm: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/pid: Permission denied
rm: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/security: Permission denied
rm: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/startup/README: Permission denied
rm: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/startup: Permission denied
rm: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/static/base/images/ipynblogo.png: Permission denied
rm: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/static/base/images: Permission denied
rm: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/static/base: Permission denied
rm: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/static/custom/custom.css: Permission denied
rm: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/static/custom/custom.js: Permission denied
rm: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/static/custom: Permission denied
rm: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/static: Permission denied
rm: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch: Directory not empty
sh: line 6: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/ipython_config.py: Permission denied
sh: line 7: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/ipython_config.py: Permission denied
sh: line 8: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/ipython_config.py: Permission denied
cp: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/static/base/images/ipynblogo.png: Permission denied
cp: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/static/custom/custom.js: Permission denied
cp: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/static/custom/custom.css: Permission denied
cp: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_itorch/profile_torch/ipython_config.py: Permission denied
cp: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_itorch/profile_torch/ipython_kernel_config.py: Permission denied
cp: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/pid: unable to copy extended attributes to /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_itorch/profile_torch/pid: Permission denied
cp: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/pid: Permission denied
cp: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/security: unable to copy extended attributes to /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_itorch/profile_torch/security: Permission denied
cp: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_torch/security: Permission denied
cp: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_itorch/profile_torch/startup/README: Permission denied
cp: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_itorch/profile_torch/static/base/images/ipynblogo.png: Permission denied
cp: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_itorch/profile_torch/static/custom/custom.css: Permission denied
cp: /Users/PJ/.ipython/profile_itorch/profile_torch/static/custom/custom.js: Permission denied
-- Found Torch7 in /Users/PJ/torch/install
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/PJ/torch/extra/iTorch/build
cd build && make install
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /Users/PJ/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/itorch/scm-1/lua/itorch/_env.lua
-- Installing: /Users/PJ/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/itorch/scm-1/lua/itorch/bokeh.lua
-- Installing: /Users/PJ/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/itorch/scm-1/lua/itorch/completer.lua
-- Installing: /Users/PJ/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/itorch/scm-1/lua/itorch/gfx.lua
-- Installing: /Users/PJ/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/itorch/scm-1/lua/itorch/init.lua
-- Installing: /Users/PJ/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/itorch/scm-1/lua/itorch/IOHandler.lua
-- Installing: /Users/PJ/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/itorch/scm-1/lua/itorch/main.lua
-- Installing: /Users/PJ/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/itorch/scm-1/lua/itorch/Plot.lua
-- Installing: /Users/PJ/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/itorch/scm-1/lua/itorch/test.lua
-- Installing: /Users/PJ/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/itorch/scm-1/lua/itorch/util.lua
-- Installing: /Users/PJ/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/itorch/scm-1/lua/itorch/bokeh-0.7.0.min.js 
-- Installing: /Users/PJ/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/itorch/scm-1/lua/itorch/bokeh-0.7.0.min.css
Updating manifest for /Users/PJ/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks
itorch scm-1 is now built and installed in /Users/PJ/torch/install/ (license: BSD)



Not updating your shell profile.
You might want to
add the following lines to your shell profile:

. /Users/PJ/torch/install/bin/torch-activate
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `install-deps` doesn't install anything python-related for MAC OSX. Try installing ipython yourself via `easy_install` or `pip`prior to running `install.sh`

Comment: Yes, I have already installed ipython. This has something to do with permissions, I guess. I do not know how to fix that.

Comment: It says ```Error: could not find ipython in PATH```. Try adding it to your PATH manually, like ```PATH=/dir/where/ipython/located/:$PATH```

Answer (score 0):

The `permission denied` suggests that you may have incorrectly run some part of this (or another?) installation script as `root` or `sudo` previously, causing some directories in your home directory to be unwritable by yourself. Maybe you can `chown` them to yourself as `root`, then fix the permissions; or maybe just remove them and start over.

Comment: You are not supplying enough details to allow us to see which directories or files have incorrect ownership and/or permissions; but this is an extremely common FAQ, so you should be able to easily find detailed instructions for resolving this.